# How to access precompiled Handlebars templates from page's javascript file rather than in html?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, templating

I have a terrain.html file and a terrain.js. I have precompiled a handlebars template (templates/favorites.precompiled.js). I am trying to reference the favorites template in the terrain.js file so I can inject the context and then append it to a container with id "output".

I can access the template fine within the HTML, but I cannot figure out what I need to do to reference it from the terrain.js file.

```
    <script src="scripts/terrain.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
    <script id="favorites-template" src="partials/favorites.precompiled.js"></script>

            <div id="output">

            </div>

            <script>
                console.log(Handlebars.templates)
            </script>
```

This outputs as expected: {favorites: ƒ}

However, if I try to print Handlebars.templates to the console in terrain.js I get undefined. I have also tried specifying the specific template Handlebars.templates['favorites'] and Handlebars.templates['templates/favorites.precompiled'] etc.

Comment: Try making `terrain.js` load last, after handlebars and the template partial (put the `<script>` tag for terrain last).

Comment: @JoshuaT
I actually had it load last initially. I changed it to the beginning thinking maybe it would make a difference, but it didn't. Should i be able to reference it in the javascript file without calling it more explicitly within that file?